# How to send data with NSNotificationCenter and reload a UITable after the data is received?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I have a `NSNotification` in `viewController1` that sends the `object:selectedTableString` 
when the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is called in `viewController1`.

The `object:selectedTableString` object is then picked up in `viewController2`. The console output is correct and the object is being picked up correctly. The issue I'm facing is how to reload (`[mainTable reloadData];`) the tableView when the notification is received in `viewController2`.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedTableString = cell.textLabel.text;

    if (cell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        if (prev!=indexPath.row) {
            cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:prev inSection:0]];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            prev=indexPath.row;
        }
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    NSLog(@"selectedTableString is %@",selectedTableString);

    NSLog(@"posting notification");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TTSelectedList" object:selectedTableString];
}
```

then in `viewController2`:

```
- (void)selectedList:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"received notification");

    theString = [notification object];

    NSLog(@"thestring is %@", theString);

    // getting an NSString
    selectedTableString = theString;

    if ([selectedTableString isEqualToString:@"Italy"]) {
        jsonStringCountry = @"http://***/v1/public/cities?country=it";
        [mainTable reloadData];
    }
    else if ([selectedTableString isEqualToString:@"Spain"]) {
        jsonStringCountry = @"http://***/v1/public/cities?country=es";
        [mainTable reloadData];
    }
    else if ([selectedTableString isEqualToString:@"UK"]) {
        jsonStringCountry = @"http://***/v1/public/cities?country=uk";
    }
    else if ([selectedTableString isEqualToString:@"Brazil"]) {
        jsonStringCountry = @"http://***/v1/public/cities?country=br";
    }

    NSLog(@"from two table selectedTableString %@",selectedTableString);

    [mainTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: this is your third question regarding the same issue. Please rephrase your previous questions, there is no need to ask the same thing over and over.

Comment: Dude use a property in second view controller and set directly. or use delegate. When there is an easy way why you are doing like this?

Comment: is mainTable non-null when you're calling reloadData?

Comment: If both tables are visible, it seems inefficient to use notifications.

Comment: So what's the problem? You say the issue is how to reload the table -- you're doing that in this code. What's not working?